# Tweetinvi: add credentials to the PublishTweetAsync method

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

I have an elevated development account in Twitter.

I'm testing [Tweetinvi](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi) with this code:

```
private async Task ConnectToTwitter()
{
    // we create a client with your user's credentials
    var userClient = new TwitterClient(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret);

    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connected";

    // request the user's information from Twitter API
    var user = await userClient.Users.GetAuthenticatedUserAsync();
    labelUserName.Text = user.Name;

    // publish a tweet
    var tweet = await userClient.Tweets.PublishTweetAsync("Hello tweetinvi world!");
    Console.WriteLine("You published the tweet : " + tweet);
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Reason : Unauthorized
Code : 401
Date : 29/05/2022 15:25:49 +02:00
URL : https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=Hello%20tweetinvi%20world%21&tweet_mode=extended
Twitter documentation description : Unauthorized -  Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect.
```

On this line of code:

```
var tweet = await userClient.Tweets.PublishTweetAsync("Hello tweetinvi world!");
```

How can I add the credentials to the `PublishTweetAsync` call?

Or maybe, there is another way to publish a tweet with credentials without using `PublishTweetAsync`?

**UPDATE**

Due to the answer of [Andy Piper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72424579/68571), I have to say that the code compiles, so all the arguments for `TwitterClient` has a value (of course, I'm not going to share them here), and I can get the `user` here:

```
var user = await userClient.Users.GetAuthenticatedUserAsync();
```

I have also enabled this:
[image]

But I don't know what to put in the Callback URI.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in your code…

```
// we create a client with your user's credentials
    var userClient = new TwitterClient(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret);
```

You need to have the values defined in your code to pass in to the `TwitterClient` instance. You also need to ensure that you have an app with access to the v1.1 API (elevated access) to use this code, since it will not work with v2.

Finally, you should check that your app has read and write permissions and that your access token and secret were generated with these permissions.

Comment: I have my credentials value defined in my code. I have elevated access.

Comment: Were the access token and secret created with read and write access?

Comment: No. I have recreated with read and write rights, and now I can work. Thanks a lot! Change your answer with these details and I accept it.